# how to send data to ajax from controller

Tags: magento2

here is my phtml file

**check_delivery.phtml**

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function ($) { 
    var dataForm = $('#check-delivery-form');
    dataForm.mage('validation', {});
    var dataFormMessage = $('#check-delivery-form .message');
    dataFormMessage.removeClass('success').removeClass('error').hide();
    $('.action-check-delivery').on('click',function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('postcode', $('#check-delivery-form input[name="postcode"]').val());
            $.ajax({

                url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkDelivery/postcode/check',['id'=> $product->getId()]) ?>',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                showLoader: true,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    dataFormMessage.removeClass('success').removeClass('error').hide();
                    dataFormMessage.addClass(response.type).html(response.message).show();
                }
            });
            return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

now here is my controller

**Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    protected $_pincodeFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\PincodeFactory $pincodeFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_pincodeFactory = $pincodeFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $pincode = $this->_pincodeFactory->create();
        $collection = $pincode->getCollection();
        foreach($collection as $item){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($item->getData());
            echo "</pre>";
        }
        exit();
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

any help on this is appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. In url change as below first                 url:  '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkDelivery/postcode/check)?>',

Comment: what you  response your want from  controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function ($) { 
    var dataForm = $('#check-delivery-form');
    dataForm.mage('validation', {});
    var dataFormMessage = $('#check-delivery-form .message');
    dataFormMessage.removeClass('success').removeClass('error').hide();
    $('.action-check-delivery').on('click',function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('postcode', $('#check-delivery-form input[name="postcode"]').val());
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkDelivery/postcode/check'),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data : {
                   formdata : formData,
                   id:<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($product->getId())) ?>
                },
                showLoader: true,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    dataFormMessage.removeClass('success').removeClass('error').hide();
                    dataFormMessage.addClass(response.type).html(response.message).show();
                }
            });
            return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Now In Controller

```
<?php
namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    protected $_pincodeFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\PincodeFactory $pincodeFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_pincodeFactory = $pincodeFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $pincode = $this->_pincodeFactory->create();
        $collection = $pincode->getCollection();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
          // Get All Data
          $data=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
          // Get FormData Only
          $formData=$this->getRequest()->getParams('formdata');
          //Get Id Only
          $id = $this->getRequest()->getParams('id');
          exit;
        }
        foreach($collection as $item){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($item->getData());
            echo "</pre>";
        }
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: please check your phtml file code i think u missed something

Comment: check my update answer .. thanks for correction

Comment: still an issue with phtml file

Comment: there is also a problem with the controller and am getting this after replacing your code with mine Type Error occurred when creating object: Learn\CheckDelivery\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor

Comment: please run php bin/magneto setup:upgrade from your magento root directory

Comment: ok and what about phtml file

Comment: please identify what is missing in phtml?

Comment: please accept m answer if it is helpful to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104351/discussion-between-pramod-and-waqar-ali).

Answer (score 1):

You can send data to your ajax success as json. See below example

```
$options = [];
foreach ($model as $item) {
    $options[] = array('model' => $item->getModel());
}
$resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
$resultJson->setData($options);
return $resultJson;
```

In your phtml you can get data like below

```
$.ajax({
      showLoader: true,
      url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('url'); ?>',
      data:  data,
      type: "POST"
}).done(function (data) {
    $('.loading-mask').hide();
    if (data.length>0) {
        var html = "<option value=''>Model</option>";
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            html += "<option value='"+ data[i].model +"' selected>"+data[i].model+"</option>";
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: am not getting it am still learning magento